# Sizing electric motor

Tags: motors, propulsion

I've been looking for a way to size an electric motor for a vehicle that could be assumed as a box-shaped load with a mass of 60 kg, up a 10° incline, at 1.6 m/s, using continuous tracks with 1 motor per side, but for some reason while searching for the answer I found different formulas for this and all of them gave me different answers.

What is the actual formula I should use to find the power required to move this load? As detailed as possible since it's for a practical application not only a theoretical question.

The last one I found is:

$$P = \frac{F_t\ v}{\eta}$$

Where $F_t = Rolling\;Resistance\; +\; Gradient\; Resistance\; + Air\; Resistance$ 
and $\eta = Transmission\; Efficiency$.

Is this the correct formula I should be using? Am I missing something? Should I consider Air Resistance since the vehicle is not moving too fast? I noticed both rolling resistance and gradient resistance have a friction coefficient, do I use the same one on both equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 1.6[m/s] the Air resistance is negligible so I would dismiss that term.

However, a word of caution: **Rolling resistance Force** is not the same as **friction force** if you are using wheels.

I would point you to the following page [for a rough estimation of Rolling resistance](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/rolling-friction-resistance-d_1303.html).

The other factors that might come into play are *negligible* compared to what you have outlined (namely **gradient** and **Rolling resistance**).

**If you use tires** (which I expect with a load of 60 kg), the equation should have a form like:

$$ P = (c\cdot W\cos(\alpha)+ W\cdot sin \alpha)v$$

which can be approximated by the following (as you mentioned in your comment):

$$ P = (c\cdot W + W\cdot sin \alpha)v$$

Comment: When calculating the gradient resistance, should I actually use a friction coefficient? I thought that maybe using tires that it wouldn't make that much of a difference, though tracks might.

So my equation in this case becomes (withut air resistance):
$$
P = (cW+ Wsin \alpha)v
$$

Comment: Oh $c$ is the rolling resistance coefficient used for calculating the rolling resistance as it says on the link you provided before. The equation I posted would be the sum of the rolling resistance and the gradient resistance times velocity. I noticed your fixed equation looks a lot like the gradient resistance with the friction coefficient.

Comment: I updated the post, basically incorporating your comments and my reply, while stressing that this is for pneumatic tires. However, I am curious as to where you got your initial equation with the Transmissability Ratio (I've encounter this term sometimes in Gear boxes or Vibration Isolation problems, so I am unsure of the context its being used). If you'd be so kind to provide a reference, I might get a better understanding of where you are coming from.

Comment: Yes, of course. I actually got the equation from the same site you [linked](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cars-power-torque-d_1784.html), I didn't notice that the page for the rolling resistance was linked at it that's why I missed it until you linked it. Just so I can understand, if I use the rolling resistance coefficient, it replaces the friction coefficient from gradient resistance?

Comment: I might be getting confused but it's best to ask than not. But would this be the correct equation? ($c$ is the rolling resistance coefficient and $\mu$ is the friction coefficient)$$P = (F_r + F_g)v = (cW + W(sin\alpha + \mu cos\alpha)))v$$

Comment: No. You will either use the rolling resistance (if you got tires) **or** the friction (if you got no tires).

Comment: Oh I see! That makes a lot more sense than what I was doing before. That probably explains why I was getting weird values. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The friction coeficient is defined by the surfaces in contact, if they don’t change then it won’t.

So tires on tarmac has a friction coeficient but that changes with rain, snow or spilt diesel...